# Upload File Processing Background

Tags: files

Is it possible when uploading a file to a node for it to upload as a background process? Ideally what I would like to do is to be able to upload files in the background while being able to continue navigating through the website. When the uploaded files are complete a notification appears on the website to say that the upload is complete or an email is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a look in the Contrib Module space, I would say no, it's not possible. The main problem as you probably already know: A file upload will break if you navigate away from the page.

However, if you have lots of time to invest in implementing this, I could imagine the following workaround: You could ajaxify your whole Drupal website, e.g. with [ajaxify](http://4nf.org/) so that some outer elements of your page will persist while your navigation is taking place and your content is rendered inside a "content" element. You could then process the file upload in e.g. an iframe that resides outside of your "content" area.

Hope this helps!